# Creating a dynamic sort method for linq to entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, linq-expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)

I'm using the Entity Framework and would like to create my own dynamic sorting method that will let you enter a string to do your sorting such as `query.DynamicSort("Name, Age DESC")`.

I know MS has put out some dynamic linq code but it's more than I need and I'm trying to understand how to write a simplified version of it myself just for sorting.

I've had some luck in getting it to work for a single field...but when I try to sort by multiple fields I get the following error:

> The parameter 'x' was not bound in the
>   specified LINQ to Entities query
>   expression.

Here's my code. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong and perhaps suggest some revisions? I'm weak on constructing expressions dynamically.

```
public static class DynamicQuery
{
    private class SortField
    {
        public Expression Expression;
        public bool       Descending = false;
        public Type       Type;
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> DynamicSort<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string sortOrder)
    {
        var fields     = sortOrder.Split(',');
        var sortFields = new List<SortField>();

        ParameterExpression arg = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
        {
            var sf = new SortField();
            sortFields.Add(sf);

            //Handle Descending Sort Fields
            if (fields[i].EndsWith(" DESC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                sf.Descending = true;
                fields[i] = fields[i].Substring(0, (fields[i].Length - 5));  //Remove " DESC"
            }

            fields[i] = fields[i].Trim();

            //Handle fields that have nested properties
            var props = fields[i].Split('.');
            sf.Type = typeof(T);
            sf.Expression = arg = Expression.Parameter(sf.Type, "x");  //Create an x parameter of type T

            foreach (string prop in props)
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = sf.Type.GetProperty(prop);
                sf.Expression = Expression.Property(sf.Expression, pi);
                sf.Type = pi.PropertyType;
            }
        }

        //Now that we have the SortFields we can do the sorting
        Expression queryExpr = source.Expression;
        string methodAsc = "OrderBy";
        string methodDesc = "OrderByDescending";
        foreach (var sf in sortFields)
        {
            LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(sf.Expression, arg);

            queryExpr = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), sf.Descending ? methodDesc : methodAsc,
                new Type[] { source.ElementType, sf.Type },
                queryExpr, Expression.Quote(lambda));
            methodAsc = "ThenBy";
            methodDesc = "ThenByDescending";
        }
        return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)source.Provider.CreateQuery(queryExpr);
    }
}
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: It is similar, and I've taken some ideas from that post, but what I'm trying to do is a bit different. I've updated my question to more fully explain.

Comment: @user, I do not understand what you mean.  The link I provided does precisely what you are asking for.  To sort by two fields, first you use `OrderBy`, and then you use `ThenBy`.  If you are having trouble, I recommend you look at the code in that question until you understand it -- I use it myself and can attest that it works great.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't allow you to pass in a valid SQL sorting string. You'd need to know ahead of time each field you wished to sort by and make the multiple calls.

Comment: @user, what do you mean by "a valid SQL sorting string"?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: I did. You are familiar with how sorting works in SQL right? Each field name comma seperated and followed by an optional ASC/DESC. At any rate I listed my specific error message that I'm interested in finding the cause of.

Comment: @user, are you **sure** you actually read the duplicate in question?  It does **exactly that**: `queryable.OrderBy("Column1").ThenByDescending("Column2")`  That snippet will order by "Column1" ascending and "Column2" descending.  **Please** give an example where this is insufficient.

Comment: @user, the *reason* your code is failing is because you are reusing the `arg` variable.   When you have this line:  `LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(sf.Expression, arg);`, **which** `ParameterExpression` is being bound?  Clearly only the last one, since `arg` gets overidden upon each iteration of the initial sort field loop.  My suggestion:  1) Add a new field to class `SortField`: `public ParameterExpression Arg;`.  2)  Remove the `arg` variable altogether and instead assign this field.  3) Refer to this field when creating the lambda: `Expression.Lambda(sf.Expression, sf.Arg);`

Comment: (I made those changes to your code and tested it: `db.Users.DynamicSort("UserId, UserName").ToArray();`.  No error anymore.  And I suspect you were trying to re-use instances of `ParameterExpression` because they were defined the same way.  This is a no-no when using expression trees.)